# Counting subarray have sum in range [L, R]

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I am solving a competitive programming problem, it was described like this:

> Given n < 10^5 integer a1, a2, a3, ..., an and L, R. How many
>   subarrays are there such that sum of its element in range [L, R].

Example:

**Input:**

```
n = 4, L = 2, R = 4
1 2 3 4
```

**Output:** 4

(4 = 4, 3 = 1 + 2 = 3, 2 = 2)

One solution I have is bruteforce, but O(n^2) is too slow. What data structures / algorithms should I use to solve this problem efficiently ?

Comment: Are the integers allowed to be negative?

Comment: @user1990169 What if there are negative numbers?

Comment: @user2040251 I see your point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compute prefix sums(p[0] = 0, p[1] = a1, p[2] = a1 + a2, ..., p[n] = sum of all numbers).

For a fixed prefix sum p[i], you need to find the number of such prefix sums p[j] that j is less than i and p[i] - R <= p[j] <= p[i] - L. One can do it in O(log n) with treap or another balanced binary search tree.

Pseudo code:

```
treap.add(0)
sum = 0
ans = 0
for i from 1 to n:
    sum += a[i]
    left, right = treap.split(sum - R)
    middle, right = right.split(sum - L)
    ans += middle.size()
    merge left, middle and right together
    treap.add(sum)
```

Comment: it is O(n log n). I mean log n for fixed i.

Comment: How did you get O(n log n) complexity when there could be (n(n-1))/2 solutions?

Comment: @HerpDerpington Count, not list all of them

Comment: But in binary search tree, how can I count how many j for a fixed i ?

Comment: @HerpDerpington get the numbers in range is a split opration(this part is log n). Get subtree size is done in constant time(if we store sizes in nodes).

Comment: @Xeing for a treap, it is two splits + one get subtree size.

Comment: Can you write pseudo code so I can understand it more clearly ?
(I am reading about treap on wikipedia)

Comment: Thank you, after learning about datastructure, I can use fenwick tree to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

We can do it in linear time if the array contains positive numbers only.

First build an array with prefix sum from left to right.

```
1. Fix three pointers, X, Y and Z and initialize them with 0
2. At every step increase X by 1
3. While sum of numbers between X and Y are greater than R keep increasing Y
4. While sum of numbers between X and Z are greater than or equal to L, keep increasing Z
5. If valid Y and Z are found, add Z - Y + 1 to result.
6. If X is less than length of the array, Go to step 2.
```

Comment: It is not correct if the initial array can contain negative values.

Comment: @user2040251 I think you can fix negative numbers by subtracting  min(list) to every value and subtract (j-i)*min(list) when calculating the value of the interval (i,j)

Comment: @HerpDerpington With subtraction, the sequence might become not increasing. And two pointers technique would not work in that case.

Comment: @HerpDerpington Look at this test case: a = {-1, 1, -1, 1, ..., -1, 1}, L = 0, R = 0.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. I've edited to state that it works if the array is of positive integers.